# Shapeless ToTraversable is not serialisable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shapeless

I am trying to use `HList` from Shapeless in a Spark `RDD`, I would like to use the `toList` method which requires the following implicit:

```
implicit ev2: ToTraversable.Aux[InType, List, OutType]
```

However, if I pass this implicit to the RDD, it throws a `NotSerializableException`:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.generic.GenTraversableFactory$$anon$1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
```

Is there an alternative way to achieve `toList` in Shapeless, or a way to provide an implicit that is serialisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading throught some of the shapeless code I found in the [tests](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/d27c58fede7655938d91631c6adc2f7a7c4ceea7/core/jvm/src/test/scala/shapeless/serialization.scala#L278) that the workaround is to put this implicit `CanBuildFrom` in scope for `ToTraversable`:

```
  implicit def listSerializableCanBuildFrom[T]: CanBuildFrom[List[T], T, List[T]] =
    new CanBuildFrom[List[T], T, List[T]] with Serializable {
      def apply(from: List[T]) = from.genericBuilder[T]

      def apply() = List.newBuilder[T]
    }
```